# Disable keyboard shortcut (delphi)

Tags: delphi, shortcut, keyboard-shortcuts

I created a form in Delphi. 
Say I have a `Form` with a `speedbutton` with label `"&Add"` (underline A, as a keyboard shortcut), and a `dbgrid` (read-only state) (or other control like `TButton`).

Then I changed the focus to `Dbgrid` (`dbgrid` got a focus) (or to `TButton`).

Every time I press the <kbd>a</kbd> key on the `dbgrid`, the `onClick` method on the `speedbutton` triggers.

Sometime I need to disable it for a while for a reason, and then i enable it again.
How to disable the `speedbutton` shortcut?
And then how to enable it again?

Answer (score 4):

The form is pressing the button when you press <kbd>A</kbd> because the button has expressed interest in that key, and nothing else on your form is accepting keystrokes. If you had an edit box on your form, and it had the input focus, then the button would not be triggered.

You can make a control indicate that it wants to receive keystrokes when it has the focus, but that generally happens when writing a custom control, where you have some idea of what the new control class should do when it receives keyboard input.

If you don't want the button to be triggered, you can disable it. Another option is to alter the OnClick event handler to check other conditions (such as whether the grid has focus) before performing the usual click-handling code.

Comment: How about using **formShortcut** event? Can we disabled it from here? I dont understand, why this event trigered twice?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the OnShortcut event would work, too. I don't know why it would fire twice, though. You could do some investigation, or you could post another question asking why it works the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the shortcut by changing the speed button's label from `&Add` to `Add`. Change it back when you need to enable the shortcut again.

Please note that specifying an accelerator character like that enables *two* shortcuts, one is just the key prefaced with the `&` and the other the same key with <kbd>Alt</kbd>. So, in your case they would be <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. In the same way, eliminating the accelerator disables both shortcuts. So, keep in mind that with this method of disabling the shortcut you would be unable to trigger the button neither with <kbd>A</kbd> nor with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.